# Inserting next row column into first row column meeting conditions using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert corresponding row `EditedDate` to `NextDate` and so on such that when `status = Passive` for `ID=502`, the corresponding row `EditedDate` i.e `2017-07-31 14:17:14.000` should be inserted into `NextDate` for `ID=502`. And when `status = Passive` for last line for `ID=1702`, then the same `EditedDate` i.e. `2017-08-01 17:30:55.000` should be inserted into the `NextDate` of the last row for `ID=1702`.

[image: Image Here]

The required output is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ6Jr.jpg]

Comment: you need show some effort, what have you tried already and so on?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Posting images of data is not really a good idea. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 A much better approach can be found here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Gosh all the downvotes are pretty harsh. Yes this question is not good but the user is brand new. Let's at least give them a chance and a little direction. It is no wonder so many new people run away from this place so quickly.

Comment: Looks like all you need is LEAD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: does anybody know to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, trying to reformulate:

you need to copy the value of column EditedDate into NextDate  for each record when status is passive? if so :

```
UPDATE YourTable SET NextDate = EditedDate WHERE status='Passive'
```

Comment: corresponding row edited date should be inserted into nextdate for ID= 502  when status = 'Passsive' and same edited date should be inserted into next date for ID= 1702  when staus = 'Passive'

Comment: Can you show an example output of what you expect as a result? 

If you just need additional conditions on the id it would be

UPDATE YourTable SET NextDate = EditedDate WHERE status='Passive' AND ID in (502,1702)

Comment: I have posted the Output. So can anybody provide the sql query

Comment: how to select maximum value of ID based on customerID

Comment: You need to use a group by i guess, this will get the max ID for each customerID (but that is a different question):

    SELECT CustomerID,MAX(ID) FROM YourTable Group by CustomerID